# Rename S3 folder structure for Athena partitioning

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I have access to an S3 bucket structured like bucket_name/year/month/day/file.gz with hundreds of files per day. I know that to define a partitioned Athena table over this data it would need to be named as bucket_name/year=year/month=month/day=day. Short of writing a shell script spelling out every day (so, a series of

```
aws cp --recursive s3://old_bucket/YYYY/MM/DD/* s3://new_bucket/year=YYYY/month=MM/day=DD/
```

for each value of YYYY/MM/DD in the dataset)

is there a simpler way to approach this? I know about `ALTER TABLE ADD PARTITION` but again it seems to require me to specify each partition individually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to rename the files at all. While it's true that most examples use the [Hive-style naming convention](https://athena.guide/articles/hive-style-partitioning/) Athena does not require it.

[There are many ways to add partitions to an Athena table](https://athena.guide/articles/five-ways-to-add-partitions/). In your case I would either go with [partition projection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partition-projection.html), which would make new data partitions available immediately. Alternatively you can add partitions manually with [`ALTER TABLE … ADD PARTITION`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/alter-table-add-partition.html).

To create a table configured with partition projection you can use this as a starting point:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE my_table (
  …
)
PARTITIONED BY (
  `date` string
)
TBLPROPERTIES (
  "projection.enabled" = "true",
  "projection.date.type" = "date",
  "projection.date.range" = "2020/01/01,NOW",
  "projection.date.format" = "yyyy/MM/dd",
  "storage.location.template" = "s3://bucket_name/${date}/"
)
```

You can then query your table with

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE "date" = '2020/10/24'
```

Note that the date column/partition key is a string and not a `DATE`. Athena will take the string and interpolate it into the URI given by `storage.location.template`. Partition projection is pretty clever, and I encourage you to [read the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partition-projection-supported-types.html) to find out what the `….range` property does, for example.

Also note that `date` is a reserved word, and to use it in DDL you must quote it in backticks, but in queries it needs to instead be quoted in double quotes. If you want to avoid having to always quote you can name it something else, but if you do you need to change the name both in the `PARTITIONED BY` part and the `TBLPROPERTIES` part.

The alternative to partition projection, which is a fairly new feature, is to add partitions manually. You can do this with the Glue Data Catalog API, which is preferable when writing code in my opinion, or you can do it with DDL, which is more compact and easier to fit into a Stack Overflow answer.

Assuming you have a table partitioned by `date` like above (but without the `TBLPROPERTIES` since those are partition projection-specific), you can add partitions like this:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD IF NOT EXISTS
PARTITION (`date` = '2020-10-22') LOCATION 's3://bucket_name/2020/10/22/'
PARTITION (`date` = '2020-10-23') LOCATION 's3://bucket_name/2020/10/23/'
PARTITION (`date` = '2020-10-24') LOCATION 's3://bucket_name/2020/10/24/'
```

You can then query your table like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE "date" = '2020-10-24'
```

Note here that I add the partitions with values for the partition keys that don't correspond exactly to how the dates are represented in the S3 URIs (I format the dates with dashes in the standard ISO way, instead of slashes). When adding partitions manually there doesn't have to be any correspondence at all between the partition keys' values and the S3 URI.

Some people will tell you that you must use Hive-style partitioning with Athena, and that you should then add partitions with `MSCK REPAIR TABLE`. This is not the case, as I hope I've shown above, and using that command to add partitions is not a good idea, it works for a few partitions, but [eventually it will start timing out](https://athena.guide/articles/msck-repair-table/).

Comment: Did you have any luck using `timestamp` as data type for the partition column? It would add some convenience and validation to queries, i.e. with string, someone could accidentally query `where date >= '2020-01-01'`, which might be a hard to spot mistake.

When I switch the column to `timestamp`, I get following error because Athena seems to urlencode the format string: `[ErrorCategory:USER_ERROR, ErrorCode:DATA_ERROR], Detail:HIVE_INVALID_PARTITION_VALUE: Invalid partition value '2019/01/01/00' for TIMESTAMP partition key: hour=2019%2F01%2F01%2F00`

Comment: You can type your partition key as `DATE` if the values are ISO formatted, e.g. `2019-01-01`. It's no different from regular columns, all that happens is that if you say that a column or partition key is of a certain type, Athena will parse them as that type, and if they don't conform to the required format a type error is thrown. ISO format is the only date format Athena recognizes. It gets confusing when you add partition projection into the mix since you can specify a date format there, but PP is a pure query planning thing, it doesn't change how Athena interprets the data.

Comment: My question was particularly about forward slashes. I can not change the directory structure because we are using AWS Firehose. (disregarding the dynamic partitioning feature they introduced yesterday)

Comment: You can change the prefix used by Kinesis Firehose and get ISO formatted dates, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/s3-prefixes.html

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It still does not answer my question.

Comment: The answer is: _if the values don't conform to the required format a type error is thrown_. I.e. `DATE` and `TIMESTAMP` columns must have values that are formatted as `YYYY-MM-DD` and `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` respectively. _No other formats will work_. If your values have slashes instead of dashes there is no workaround except for configuring your firehose to write keys differently.